# Resolution issue on MS-1013 running XP

Tags: windows-xp, laptop, resolution, windows-installer

I have an old laptopt (MSI MS-1013), its screen's back-light died before I got it, so I have to use an external screen. I installed Lubuntu on it last year and never turned it on again.

Today I wanted to install XP on it to play some old games, but during BIOS, installation and usage of win XP, the resolution is a mess. I tried with 3 different screens, two 4:3 and on 16:10 with all the resolutions I could set, but I always end up with something more or less unusable, like so (this is the best result I had for now) :

[image]

I am going to install one or two games, to see if a full screen application will change anything but I doubt it.
What's bothering me is that it was perfect in Lubuntu, but not in the BIOS.

What do you think about it, what should I try ?
Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

Part of me wonders if you changed the resolution in the settings.  Ensure the screen resolution in Windows Display Settings matches what the laptop LCD supports.

However, it sounds like you merely need to install the correct video drivers for the particular brand of GPU in the laptop.

My **guess** from using the Google machine is that the GPU is an: **ATI Radeon Xpress 200M**  but you will need to look at the spec's of your particular model/version.

Download and install those drivers
Change the video resolution as desired.
Enjoy.

PS:  aside from the blurriness of the image, aligning the camera with the photo subject would do wonders for making it more useful.

Comment: I did forgot to try to install the drivers at the time of my post (long time away from Windows) but it didn't change much, just gave me more options.
There was two drivers available (one from 2006, one from 2010) neither of them changed much. At the moment it's just black screen, not even "outside of range" error that I'd encountered before.
Native resolution of the screen is 1280*800, but it's as bad as the other resolutions.
I can take another picture but given the results I'm not sure it will help.
Is there anything, beside the drivers that could be at fault ?